# Adding text BELOW bitmap in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, image-processing

I'm trying to resize a .NET bitmap without actually scaling the image. The idea here is to create a space above and below the image, fill it with a black rectangle, and place some text there (without covering up or destroying any part of the original image).

All the code and examples I've seen of this thus far just show how to scale the image, not expand the canvas. So far, everything I've tried on my own also scales/stretches the image.

Here's what I have:

```
Dim imageSize As System.Drawing.Size
Dim exifImage As Image

exifImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(originalPath)

imageSize.Height = exifImage.Height
imageSize.Width = exifImage.Width
imageSize.Height += BLAH '' whatever I need to add to my height for the text
'' this doesn't work, because the image gets stretched instead of stuff getting added above and below

Dim exifOverlayImage As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(exifImage, imageSize)

Dim graphic As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(exifOverlayImage)
graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
graphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality

'' Draw Title at the Top
Dim upperBackgroundRectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, imageSize.Width, pointFontSize * 2)
graphic.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, upperBackgroundRectangle)
graphic.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, upperBackgroundRectangle)
graphic.DrawString(upperTitleCommentString, watermarkFont, New SolidBrush(Color.White), New Point(0, 3))

'' ... and more stuff ...
```

I suspect that I need to change some sort of scaling mode, or perhaps create a new canvas or something that's larger than my original image? Thoughts/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it slightly differently. Here's the function that does the work:

```
'' new function which creates a new image which is taller by extraHeight, and pastes the source image into it at pasteHeight
Private Function addBufferToImage(ByVal source As Image, ByVal backgroundColor As Color, ByVal extraHeight As Integer, ByVal pasteHeight As Integer) As Image
    Dim newBitmap As New Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height + extraHeight)
    Dim graphic As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap)
    graphic.Clear(backgroundColor)
    graphic.DrawImage(source, 0, pasteHeight) ' draw the original at (0, pasteHeight) on the new image
    graphic.Dispose()
    Return newBitmap
End Function
```

And then I call the function in my code:

```
'' create a new Bitmap Object
Dim exifOverlayImage As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(originalImage, originalImageSize)
exifOverlayImage = addBufferToImage(exifOverlayImage, Color.Black, extraHeight, pasteHeight)
'' now I can write text in the new blank areas of the image
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a bitmap with consideration of the newly added width and height. This is how I did it (it's in C# but you can use [www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/&rct=j&q=c#%20to%20vb%20convert&ei=KWKRTaH3IMrUsgb01PGqDw&usg=AFQjCNFM321pCrxs_o-P69sgwPbmfGp0Rw&sig2=oky_QHOqQpxH2xyqw-s1MA&cad=rja) to convert it): (**width + pixelPadding** and ** height + bottomSize + pixelPadding** is where the paddings are added.)

```
            using (
          var dst = new Bitmap(width + pixelPadding, height + bottomSize + pixelPadding, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
        {
            var rSrcImg = new Rectangle(0,0, src.Width, src.Height);
            var rDstImg = new Rectangle(pixelPadding / 2, pixelPadding/2, dst.Width - pixelPadding, dst.Height - pixelPadding - bottomSize);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(dst))
            {
                g.Clear(Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64));
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rDstImg);

                g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
                g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.GammaCorrected;
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

                g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
                g.DrawImage(src, rDstImg, rSrcImg, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }

            var ms = new MemoryStream();

            // save the bitmap to the stream...
            dst.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            ms.Position = 0;
```

I've written a blog post about it at http://www.devzone.ir/post/1389/09/16/Dynamic-Thumbnails-in-ASP.aspx. It resizes *and* adds some padding to the image.
Basically, you have to create a bitmap of size image + paddings. Then fill a rectangle with your image and draw a string in your desired area.
The article is in Persian but you can use Google Translate. I have provided the source code there.